# Eclipse and SASS/LESS automatically compile

Tags: eclipse, sass, eclipse-plugin, less

Im looking for an up to date solution for automatically compiling SASS or LESS in Eclipse IDE.

Looking at some older threads it looks like there are plugins but not sure which would be most suitable nor how to configure it.

Comment: What do you mean by _"running SASS or LESS"_? [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) has editors for SASS and LESS.

Comment: What I mean is something that will automatically compile SASS or LESS for Eclipse. How would one set that up?

Comment: As far as I know, the common way to make CSS from SASS is via npm:  in `package.json` (create the file when you do not have one yet) specify the command (e.g. see [step 4 here](https://medium.com/@saul_scs/the-easiest-way-to-watch-and-compile-sass-in-5-steps-9021c5830cd7#fb99)) and right-click to run it as npm.